# Add mod_mam for ejabberd in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ejabberd

I have successfully configured ejabberd 2.1.10 in ubuntu 12.04 environment with mysql storage. Now I need to integrate mod_mam module for my chat server. I have downloaded the mysql modules from the url https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/ and configured using the steps mentioned here https://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd-modules. But I couldn't find the mod_mam library in that repository.

At the same time, I installed ejabberd 16.02 in my windows 7 machine and found that the mod_mam is available by default. Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: install latest ejabberd server on ubuntu why you are installing old version.

Comment: latest version support XEP-0313  check here https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/

Comment: mod_mam cannot work on ejabberd 2.1. It is far too old.

Comment: Thanks Sunil...This is the first time I am trying ejabberd. What I did was, I executed the command `sudo apt-get install ejabberd` from ubuntu terminal and it installed ejabberd 2 in my machine. After seeing your comments only, i came to know that ejabberd old version does not support mod_mam. Now I installed the latest version 16.04 and message archiving is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install latest version of ejabberd server put the following lines in module section of ejabberd.yml-

```
mod_mam:
    db_type: odbc    ##mnesia|odbc
    default: always   ##always|never|roster
    request_activates_archiving: true       ##true|false
    assume_mam_usage: on_request                ##if_enabled|on_request|never
    cache_size: 1000
    cache_life_time: 3600
```

[for detail configration check here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modmam)